# EF/Code First Migration - implicit table mappings?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am using a code first migration approach to creating new tables in an existing database, and I'd like to know if this is auto-creating a property-to-field mapping somewhere in the project.

For example: the "Category" table pre-existed in the database. It was created directly in SQL, and my MCV project has a CategoryMap.cs file that explicitly maps the Category entity properties to the Category table fields:

**CategoryMap.cs**

```
this.ToTable("Category", "ctt");
this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
this.Property(t => t.ClientId).HasColumnName("ClientId");
this.Property(t => t.CategoryTypeId).HasColumnName("CategoryTypeId");
etc.
```

The db context class explicitly points to this mapping in the OnModelCreating method:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CategoryMap());
etc.
```

With this set-up, I can save data to the Category table, as long as I keep the mapping pieces in place.

On the other hand, I've created a new table using the code first approach:

1) Create a "MyTable" entity class

2) Add this code to my context class:

```
public DbSet<MyTable> MyTable { get; set; }
```

3) Run the add-migration and update-database commands

That created a "MyTable" table in the database schema, and I can save data to this table, despite the fact that there is no mapping file, and no explicit mapping code in the OnModelCreating method of my db context class.

Now, if I comment out the "modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CategoryMap());" line of code in the context class, I can't save data to that table any more; I get a "table 'Category' not found" error message when I try to do db.SaveChanges().

So I guess my question is this: when I created "MyTable" using the add-migration and update-database commands, did a class-to-table map get auto-generated somewhere behind the scenes? If so, can I access it and view it?

Comment: As for the `not found` error; That could be because your Migration data and your database are out of sync.  For example: Somebody created the Category table directly in SQL, but your migrations don't know about it.  Or the opposite, your migrations believe there is such a table, but somebody manually altered or deleted the table.  Lastly, keep the schema in mind.  If you specified a default schema in EF, and either your mappings or the database reflect a different schema for the Category table, it would also give you this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no auto generated mappings as such but a number of mapping conventions that get applied if there are no specific mappings. For example if you have no explicit table mapping then by convention it will map to a table that matches the class name.

So for a class `Category` it will by convention map to a table called `Category`.

This is also true of properties so `Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");` doesn't actually do anything as the property will have that mapping by convention. You only need explicit mappings when you go outside the conventions. So if you wanted to map you property Id to a column called `Category_id` then you would need a column mapping  `Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Category_id");`

Read this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj679962.aspx) article for more info on the default conventions.

Comment: That makes sense; however, if this is the case, why do I get the error "table 'Category' not found" when I remove the explicit Category mapping? I have a Category entity class, so shouldn't the convention be to look for a table named "Category" and find it? It's almost as if the table HAS to have been created with the code first migration in order to work.

Comment: If there is a table called Category then yes it should work, the error seems to indicate there isn't one.

Comment: I'll be damned. Somehow the "MyTable" table (created via migration) is in the "dbo" schema, but the rest of the tables are in a different schema. So I guess that would explain why even though "Category" table exists, the error is being thrown anyway. I'm guessing I would have to use the OnModelCreating() method to specify that "Category" exists in a different schema?

Comment: Yes you need to explicitly map tables that are not in the DBO schema. You can specify the schema as the second parameter in ¬ToTable()`.

Comment: Thanks, this was massively helpful, I have a much better grasp on how the code first conventions and mapping interact.